# How to make the text that are typed inside the input to appear into a seperate div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've a input field and a separate paragraph. Now how do I get the text that are typed inside the input to also to appear inside the paragrah.?

### HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" />
<p>facebook/<span>your.username</span> </p>
```

### CSS

```
input{
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}
span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `keyup` event:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {
        var username = $(this).val();

        if(username.length > 0) {
           $('p > span').html(username);
        } else{
           $('p > span').html('your.username');
        }
    });
});
```

See working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/yqt8tx3b/2/

Comment: GREAT WORK :)

This is the exact what I wanted :)

Comment: Can you do me a improvement in this?

Comment: If I type and erase I want the default text to appear?
how to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78505/discussion-between-mohamed-and-mivaweb).

Comment: can you come to chat room?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // When DOM is ready to be manipulated

    $('input').on('keyup', function() {
        // On each key-up in textbox

        $('p span').text($.trim($(this).val()) || 'your.username');
        // Set the value of textbox inside the span
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4yfswj3p/

Answer (score 2):

This way you can make live changes in p tag.

```js
$('#txt').on('input',function(e){
      $('p').html($(this).val());
});
```

```css
input{
width: 300px;
height: 30px;
}
span {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<p>facebook/<span>your.username</span> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution, using the `input` event that will update the contents of another element as you type and also includes a check on whether or not the `input` element is empty.

```js
var input=document.getElementById("input"),output=document.getElementById("output");
input.addEventListener("input",function(){
    output.innerHTML="facebook.com/"+(this.value.trim()||"your.username");
},0);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<p id="output">facebook.com/your.username</p>
```

Comment: AWESOME :) 
This is what I wanted. I would be better with jquery I suppose.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I'm not a jQuery guy but I'd imagine it should be fairly easy to rewrite this. I've given it a try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ge7ky85/) using some of the other answers as a guildeline but it seems that `$.trim($(this).val()` is never `true`. I've also simplified my code above a bit.

Comment: Thanks Man. :) Great Work ;)

Comment: Reply me on the chat room.